# 1Password Style custom Action Menu

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, contextmenu

I just have a quick question. In the 1Password app on the iPhone/iPad when you tap the password field it gives you a non-standard option in the context-menu. I was wondering how this could be recreated with some other non-standard options like "Copy/Email/Something else".

** This does not pertain to passwords and text masking

[Custom Action Menu Options http://cl.ly/b8e92af85937086308f3/content](http://cl.ly/b8e92af85937086308f3/content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iPad, and on the iPhone running OS 4.0 or later, you can use `UIMenuController` class's `menuItems` property. If they're doing the same thing on iOS versions prior to 3.2, then it's probably a custom-built view that just looks like the usual context menu.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll just use the OS4 one.